# List files in a directory having more than one space

Tags: python, file-handling

I have this code:

```
for f in os.listdir(ftpUploaddir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ftpUploaddir,f)):
        #Filter files having .png as extension
        if f[-4:] == ".png":
            print "from directory", f
```

It does not list the files having nore than one space, e.g:

```
100002044_A   h_HD_XXX_20120229_141236.png
```

There are 3 spaces between `A` and `h`.

I know single space will be listed but not multiple spaces

Even `ls` will not list the files using `ls/*.png` Any help appreciated

Comment: If I do `touch "test   file"; ls test*` the file shows fine, so ls has no problem with these files.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Your file system seems to be somehow broken.  Or maybe there's another non-printable character after `.png`?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  And are you *sure* that the file you expect to find actually exists?  I.e., can you do an "ls -l" (or some equivalent on whatever OS you're using) showing the file?

Comment: Could you produce a complete, runnable example that creates such a file, then tries to see it using `os.listdir()` and fails?

Comment: I created two test files `touch test.png; touch "test   two.png"`, then ran your code setting ftpUploaddir to the location of these files (in /tmp) and it works just fine. What happens if you list every f returned by os.listdir, are the files with spaces there? if not, then it means os.listdir is *not* returning them, which may be a platform-specific quirk, or a problem with the filesystem itself, since you say ls doesn't show them either. Which OS and version of Python are you using? Which filesystem are you using in ftpUploaddir? ext4, NTFS, FAT, HFS?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this to see if the file is really there -- perhaps (as Sven suggested) there's a space or some other character after the ".png"?

```
for f in os.listdir(ftpUploaddir):
    if "h_HD_XXX_20120229_141236" in f
        print "Full name is %r" % f
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ftpUploaddir,f)):
            print "  (but it's not a file?)"
```

Comment: Thanks guys !! Sorry a very silly mistake i would say.You are right **@Sven** the file actually got generated has space between name and png hence wouldn't get listed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem. Try running this Python script:

```
# create a file with multiple spaces in the name
outf = open("100002044_A   h_HD_XXX_20120229_141236.png", "w")
outf.write("hello, world")
outf.close()

# see if os.listdir can find it
import os
print "100002044_A   h_HD_XXX_20120229_141236.png" in os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

For me, it's always printing True.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `fnmatch` module but can't reproduce the problem.

```
>>> import os
>>> import fnmatch
>>> os.listdir(r'C:\Users\RanRag\python\test')
['gameicon.png', 'grass i test.png', 'hello.txt']

>>> for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\RanRag\python\test'):
...          if fnmatch.fnmatch(file , '*.png'):
...                             print file
...
gameicon.png
grass i test.png
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ls command should be: `ls *.png`. If you really used a slash, it's no surprise it's not working.

I'd check if your `ftpUploaddir` is correct: Is your script finding *any* files when you run it? With the right path, your script should work as written.

Incidentally, it's easier to find files with a particular extension like this:

```
import glob, os
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(ftpUploaddir, "*.png")):
    print f
```